# Attaching a remote debug to tanuki service wrapper application

Tags: java, debugging, tanuki

I am attempting to configure an application for remote debugging. I am attempting to use the instructions under https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/qna-eclipse-remote.html and have added the following lines to my wrapper.conf

```
wrapper.java.additional.16=-Xdebug
wrapper.java.additional.17=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=y
```

When I start my application using console console the application does **not** freeze with the following:

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8001

instead it carries on running and I cannot connect to it. Can anyone advise what settings I may be missing in order to allow the application to be remotely debugged.

Answer (score 0):

One of the earlier configuration number was commented out

```
#wrapper.java.additional.13
```

This appears to mean that 14,15,16,17 were also ignored. I re-numbered these and can now debug.